# Can't return more than two operands of Zeckendorf representation

Tags: c#, math, sequence, fibonacci, addition

**Foreword: Zeckendorf representation**

This mathematical theorem states that for each number n, there are k addition operands all present in the Fibonacci sequence {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 et al}. For example, we got 100. To find its Zeckendorf representation, we first must find the largest value smaller or equal to 100 present in the Fibonacci sequence. In this case, it's 89. 100-89 is 11. The same process repeated gives us 8, and then 3. Therefore 89+8+3 = 100. This works for all numbers. If you have a strong computer that doesn't overflow with large numbers, and if you have a programming language supervised for math that holds numbers with large values, you can calculate the Zeckendorf representation for almost any given number.

However since we're using C# that's tricky with types and how large the numbers are, we have to practice caution when dealing with Zeckendorf representation. I used `long` to hold my numbers, and I calculated 20th number of the Fibonacci sequence.

```
    static void Fbonacci_Init(int roof)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < roof; i++) //where roof = 20
        {
            Fibonacci.Add(Fibonacci[i - 1] + Fibonacci[i]);
        }                    
    }
```

I then created two `public static` lists as fields:

```
    public static List<long> Fibonacci = new List<long>() { 0, 1 };
    public static List<long> ZeckendorfRep = new List<long>();
```

And then created a function called `FindLesser` than finds the a value lesser or equal to `long given argument` and adds it to `ZeckendorfRep`:

```
    static void FindLesser(long number)
    {


        for (int i = Fibonacci.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (Fibonacci[i] <= number)
            {

                ZeckendorfRep.Add(Fibonacci[i]);
                 break;                             

            }

        }

    }
```

And function called `Difference` for recursion of both FindLesser() and itself:

```
    static void Difference(long init)
    {

        FindLesser(init - ZeckendorfRep[0]);

        long summation = ZeckendorfRep.Sum();

        if (summation != init)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < ZeckendorfRep.Count; i++)
            {
                long difference = ZeckendorfRep[i] - ZeckendorfRep[i - 1];
                FindLesser(difference);
                Difference(difference);
            }
        }

    }
```

I then call each function with the argument `long input` which is `Console.ReadLine()`.

Anyways, the code doesn't work properly. It only returns the first two operands of a given representation, for example, for 100, it only returns 89 and 8. What could be the problem?

Comment: I think you need to debug the code step by step and check where it is failing to follow your desired logic.

Comment: @user3185569: I'd be not worth the air I breathe if I haven't already done that. But firstly, debugging is an skill that is required through time and experience and it's been less than a month since I've started coding. Secondly, I think the problem lies in recursion. I'm completely clueless about recursions and I hope you guys can help me understand it better.

Comment: If you're completely clueless about recursions then you need to start with a simple problem using recursion that's easy to debug.  You're basically asking strangers on the internet to debug a complicated math problem using complicated programming constructs for you.